# How to derive specific heat of a crystalline material from phonon density of states?

Tags: thermodynamics, vibrations, thermal-conductivity, phonons, density-functional-theory

I have done a simulation of a crystalline material using DFT and have extracted its normal modes and its phonon density of states.

Does anyone have an algorithm/code or a detailed resource that can extract a crystalline material's specific heat or heat capacity form the phonon density of states ?  What are other thermal properties that I can extract from the phonon-DOS ?